# Detecting a browser type

Tags: asp.net, firefox, cross-browser, browser-testing

Together with error reporting in my asp.net app, I am also retreiving browser information. For example I am getting specific error a lot:

```
Type = Mozilla
Name = Mozilla
Version = 5.0
Major Version = 5
Minor Version = 0
Platform = Unknown
Is Beta = False
Is Crawler = False
Is AOL = False
Is Win16 = False
Is Win32 = False
Supports Frames = False
Supports Tables = False
Supports Cookies = False
Supports VBScript = False
Supports JavaScript = False
0.0
Supports Java Applets = False
Supports ActiveX Controls = False
```

My first idea was firefox, but I also get firefox in specific errors, so I am not sure what exact browser is from the information above?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the user-agent string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TRY BELOW

Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
```

// Getting Browser Name of Visitor

```
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("MSIE"))
  browser = "Internet Explorer";
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("FireFox"))
  browser = "Fire Fox";
if (Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].Contains("Opera"))
  browser = "Opera";
```

Comment: HTTPUserAgent = Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, it will get you the data you need about your browser:
`System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;`

Comment: Still, this does not tell which type of browser is being used!!