# Is there a way to install a browser detector into an existing application?

Tags: asp.net, browser-detection

We would like to see which browsers are being used to access our web application, but the current software does not have any browser detection built in, and we'd rather not modify it to do this.

Is there a method of getting an ASP.NET web application to run an ad hoc app to briefly note the browser being used when the user first accesses the start page, but that doesn't try to track the browser being used on any other page?

E.g. is there some sort of web.config entry that could do it?

**Edited to Add**: I see I wasn't clear enough that this was desired to be done WITHOUT making any changes to underlying code.  Putting javascript into the .aspx file (without recompiling) would probably work -- although I don't think we can use Google Analytics inside an intranet... or can we?  I already know how to check Request.UserAgent inside C#.  I am unclear on how to do it outside of C#.  For example, is there something I can put into the web.config that would cause execution of a helper that would check Request.UserAgent?  Or some IIS setting that might launch an arbitrary application that checks browser identity?

Comment: [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) can do this. You can add it to your application by adding a small section of JavaScript to the footer of your start page.

Comment: or just get it the values and save it off yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549706/detecting-a-browser-type

Answer (score 0):

Yes – you can do this using user-agent property.

Browsers are identified through `Request.UserAgent` but note that this can be altered if someone sends a low lever http request to your server they can enter whatever they like for user agent. 
There probably won’t me many of those anyway.

I’d suggest you create a filter for user agent property so that it doesn’t store requests from Google Bot and other search engines, RSS feed readers and such.

Here is an extensive list of user agents for different browsers and web crawlers.

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/

http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

Comment: Yes, but I already know how to do all of this.  I am trying to find out if there is some way to cause execution of a process to do it as an adjunct to the current execution pathway, without modifying the compiled code.